R Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_CERT_EXPIRED (0x80090328)
I am trying to use locuszoomr::link_LD. I am getting the error message as follows. I have been stuck in this problem for a long time, so any advice is appreciated.
> loc <- locuszoomr::link_LD(loc, token = "My_TOKEN")
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_CERT_EXPIRED (0x80090328) - The received certificate has expired.
Matched 0 SNPs (0.25 secs)

I am using R version 4.3.3., and ssl_version "(OpenSSL/3.1.2) Schannel".
I've searched the error code and it was very difficult to find a solution.

Are you running on Windows? If so, what Windows version are you using? Can you connect to https://ldlink.nih.gov/LDlinkRest/ldproxy in your browser without an error/warning about the certificate (you'll likely still get a message about a missing API token but that's fine)

Thank you for your help! I am running on Windows 11, version 23H2. And yes, I can connect to your link in my browser without error about the certificate. Otherwise, I get this message: '{
"error": "API token missing. Please register using the API Access tab: https://ldlink.nih.gov/?tab=apiaccess"
}'

I am still challenged by this certificate expiration error... I would appreciate any further advice!

Interestingly, this error does not appear when I run my code from my lab's server computer. Any thoughs on why this is happening? I wish I could run my code on my PC.
